# Excel Will not Import a Table From Access

Tags: excel, ms-access

I'm Using Excel/Access 2007.  I made an Access query in Access, and I tried to import it into Excel using The Data Tab -> Get External Data Subtab -> From Access.  I chose my Database, and chose the Query I wanted to import.  However, only the headers of the table as well as 2 blank lines show up (as evidenced by their being formatted as a table).  There is definitely data that is returned in the query, that I can verify by checking Access.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

As an aside, can this be done programatically?

EDIT: Here is the SQL query in all it's glory

```
SELECT [Meter#], [LDC#], [ESCO#], [Brand], [LDCName], [RateClass], [RateSubClass], [CustName],   
[DemandZone], [Type], dbo_Forecasts.Name AS ForecasForecastType, 
Min(IntervalMeterConsumption.[DateFrom]) AS ConsumptionStart, IntermediateLog.[MaxOfDateRead] AS ConsumptionEnd, 
Sum([kWh])/(Sum([Interval])/365) AS AverageAnnual

FROM (IntermediateLog 
        INNER JOIN (
                    (Premise INNER JOIN Meters ON Premise.PremiseCt = Meters.PremiseCt) 
                    INNER JOIN IntervalMeterConsumption 
                        ON Meters.Meterid = IntervalMeterConsumption.MeterID) 
            ON IntermediateLog.[LDC#] = Premise.CustomerPremiseNo) 
INNER JOIN dbo_Forecasts ON Meters.ForecastID = dbo_Forecasts.ForecastID

WHERE ((([MaxOfDateRead]-[DateFrom])<=380))

GROUP BY IntermediateLog.[Meter#], IntermediateLog.[LDC#], IntermediateLog.[ESCO#], 
IntermediateLog.Brand, IntermediateLog.LDCName, IntermediateLog.RateClass, 
IntermediateLog.RateSubClass, IntermediateLog.CustName, IntermediateLog.DemandZone, 
IntermediateLog.Type, dbo_Forecasts.Name, IntermediateLog.MaxOfDateRead;
```

Comment: I removed them in this posting in lieu of brevity

Comment: Ok I added the full query, if you still care.  And my reaction above was because I thought you could have made your point better than using the phrase "Do not tell us 'Here is the SQL query', then show us something which is not the query". Feathers got a bit ruffled, my bad.

Comment: What data access method are you using from Excel? I know for instance that Word 2007 defaults to OLEDB for a lot of the wizards, which means that valid Access queries that use ANSI 89 SQL (e.g., `LIKE "Fent*"`) don't return any rows when executed from Word via OLEDB. I don't see anything obvious in your SQL that's going to be interpreted differently in SQL 92 vs. SQL 89, but that's where I'd start looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try removing the where clause just temporarily to see if that makes a difference.

When you run the query in Access does it ask for a parameter?

The code to export a query to Excel from Access is as follows:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Query/Table Name", "c:\export.xls"
```

thanks Mark